# Convert synchronous "foreach item in IEnumerable" to equivalent asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, ienumerable, observablecollection

Currently I have two classes in a MVVM project:

- The `Presenter` class, that has an `ObservableCollection<T>` and an operation to populate it from the items loaded from the `Loader` class;
- The `Loader` class itself, with the operation `GetItems()` that deserializes files found inside a given directory.

The code is below.

Although the file loading is made in parallel, I can only populate the ObservableCollection once all the files are loaded, which is of course a bad approach.

My goal would be to convert `Populate`/`GetItems` into something that would return right after the call, and the loaded items would "pop up" in the ObservableCollection as soon as they get loaded.

I can think of something along the lines of `Parallel.ForEach`, `IObservable`s, events, but I'll have to admit I'm quite lost with the possible alternatives.

```
class Presenter
{
    public ObservableCollection<TVM> ItemsVM {get;}
        = new ObservableCollection<TVM>();

    public Loader _loader 
    = new Loader(some_well_known_directory_path);

    void Populate()
    {
        foreach (T t_item in _loader.GetItems())
        {
            ItemsVM.Add(new TVM(t_item));
        }
    }
}

class Loader
{
    readonly string _path;

    public Loader(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems()
    {
        var result_list = new List<T>();

        Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(_path), fname =>
        {
            try
            {
                result_list.Add(T.Load(fname));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Warn(e.Message);
            }
        });

        return result_list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of situation that Rx (System.Reactive) is good for.

Try this:

```
class Presenter
{
    public ObservableCollection<TVM> ItemsVM { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<TVM>();

    public Loader _loader
        = new Loader(some_well_known_directory_path);

    void Populate()
    {
        _loader
            .GetItems()
            .Subscribe(t_item => ItemsVM.Add(new TVM(t_item)));
        }
    }
}

class Loader
{
    readonly string _path;

    public Loader(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public IObservable<T> GetItems()
    {
        return
            Observable
                .Defer(() =>
                    Directory
                        .EnumerateFiles(_path)
                        .ToObservable()
                        .SelectMany(fname => Observable.Start(() => T.Load(fname)));
    }
}
```

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek - Why? Would you have preferred to see a `.SelectMany` call?

Comment: yeah, those 3 lines do the same as `Directory.EnumerateFiles(_path).ToObservable().Select(fname => Observable.Start(() => T.Load(fname)).SelectMany(x => x);`

Comment: Or better yet, `Directory.EnumerateFiles(_path).ToObservable().SelectMany(fname => Observable.Start(() => T.Load(fname));`